# How to convert time format from Moment to D3?

Tags: node.js, d3.js, momentjs

In Node, I am using Moment for time and on the front-end I am using the D3 package. For moment, I will get a time of 1429588800 which is converts to "Tue Apr 21 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400". But in D3, I get "05/031976". This is with the format "%x".

Comment: Show us some code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I believe is that you use seconds ([unix timestamp](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/)). If you multiply it by 1000 it should work. Here are some [tests](http://jsfiddle.net/KWRxW/2038/) for you

```
var value = 1429588800;

var f = d3.time.format("%x");
var date = new Date(value*1000);
var moment_date = moment.unix(value);

console.log('date',date); //date Tue Apr 21 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
console.log('moment date',moment_date.format()); //moment date 2015-04-21T00:00:00-04:00
console.log('d3 + moment date',f(moment_date.toDate())); //d3 + moment date 04/21/15
console.log('d3 + date',f(date)); //d3 + date 04/21/15
```